# How do I know if a rake task has been invoked from another task or from the shell?

Tags: ruby, rake

Let's say we have:

```
task :something => [:something_else] do
  # some of stuff
end

task :something_else do
  # some verbose stuff
  # some quiet stuff
end
```

Now I want `something_else` to do the verbose stuff when called from the shell (`rake something_else`) and the silent ones when called as a dependency to `rake something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it might be a better idea to work with parameters or different tasks instead.

one thing that you could do is look for top-level task like that:

```
task :something_else do |t|
  puts "some verbose stuff" if t.application.top_level_tasks.include? 'something_else'
  puts "some quiet stuff"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look what was passed to ARGV. For example:

```
task :something_else do
    if ARGV[0] == 'something_else'
       puts "Verbose Stuff!"
    end
end
```